# Responding to an HTML element to change background and text of a DIV using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have an element that returns a value of either `true` or `false` when I run `$('#myId').val()`.

Once true or false is returned, I want to have a particular `div` change its background color to green for true or red for false.

```
if ($('#myId').val())
{
   code should return a div with text and green background
}
else
{
   code should return a div with text and red background
}
```

Comment: Do you need to create this `div` or it's already on the page?

Comment: Looking at your logic, no need of any if/else here!

Comment: I believe you mean div with text and red background in your else statement and we need to know if you want to dynamically create this div or if you are just wanting to change the CSS properties of an existing div

Comment: It doesn't matter but the div should be visible if true and invisible if false. Only one should show.

Comment: @Mark you are right that is what I want.

Comment: @PalashMondal right as long as I get what I need ..

Comment: Please be aware that the string `"false"` will evaluate to `true` in `javascript`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to convert the string to a bool to evaluate properly.  I have a button in the fiddle to return the value.

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bfelda/rFFGc/)

HTML:

```
<div id="myDiv">
    <input id="myID" value="false"/>
    <input id="myBtn" type="button" value="submit"/>
</div>
```

JQuery:

```
$('#myBtn').on('click', function () {
    $('#myDiv').css('background', (($('#myID').val() == "true") ? 'green' : 'red'));
});
```

Comment: Thank you for your input. I would have marked yours as answer but someone already answered. Thanks for jsfiddle.

Answer (score 2):

I'd say do a default green background class and then us an override class to add the red background. Your code would look something like this:

```
if ($('myId').val())
{
    $('myId').addClass('falseClass');
} else {
    $('myId').removeClass('falseClass');
};
```

Use CSS to add the background colors, like so:

```
.divClass{
background: green;
}

.divClass.falseClass{
background: red;
}
```

If you want to add a div with some specific text (say to whatever 'myId' marks), and then change the color, you can add the div first.

```
$('<div class="divClass">').appendTo('myId').text('foo')

if ($('myId').val())
{
    $('myId').addClass('falseClass');
} else {
    $('myId').removeClass('falseClass');
};
```

Comment: Thank you I used your suggestion and combined it with some I thought will make sense and came up with this.

Look below for my answer.

Answer (score 1):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
if ($('#myId').val()){
    showDiv("green");
}else{
    showDiv("red");
}

function showDiv(color){
    var text = "Hello world";
    return "<div class=\""+color+"\">"+text+"</div>";
}
</script>

<style>
.green{
    background-color:green;
}

.red{
    background-color:red;
}
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked best for me:

```
  if ($('#myID').val()) {
       $('#SOMECLASS').text('Some Text').css('background-color', 'green');
  else
       $('#SOMECLASS').text('Some Text').css('background-color', 'red');
  }
```